# My object deforms in a weird way when when using G (Grab)

Tags: edit-mode

I'm new to the community and started learning blender with blender guru's donut tutorials. However, whenever I use the key G, the object I am editing deforms in an abnormal way (Making sprinkles), despite the fact that they have previously worked well..[image: I am trying to elongate the figure..]

[image]

Comment: please share your file over here      https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: It Looks like un-subdivision or Decimate operator was used instead ... Is it possible you accidentally assigned shortcut G to this? I just don't know how accidentally :) see your Keymap under Preferences what key  is assigned to them ...

Comment: ... or there is a more chance you have accidentally enabled Snap tool ;)